# Can I track single emails with CiviCampaign?

Tags: contacts, email, civicampaign

I understand that I can associate mass mailings with campaigns through CiviCampaign. However, it seems that I cannot associate a single contact interaction via email to a campaign. Is that correct?

Scenario: Our NGO regularly has to stay in contact with individuals, e.g. journalists, to promote our individual projects for time periods of usually 6 months. Therefore, we separate these into Campaigns. But as it looks, I cannot associate an individual contact interaction with such an individual campaign/project, right?

Thanks for your help,
Bijan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct; the email UI (user interface) doesn't allow you to specify a campaign. However, the underlying database table is `civicrm_activity`, which DOES support storing an associated campaign.

You could write an extension (or hire someone to write an extension) that adds this functionality to CiviCRM, and because the underlying table supports what you're doing, it's relatively little work.